# How to set up two models having a has_many association with each other

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm looking for a suggestion on how to set up two models, Teacher and Subject. A Teacher can have many Subjects, and a Subject can have many Teachers. Another thing to consider in the relationship between the two models is that a Teacher can create a Subject and add other Teachers to the Subject.

I think I'm solid on the basics of the set up for each model:

for teacher.rb:

```
has_many :subjects
```

for subject.rb:

```
has_many :teachers
```

and the teachers table should have a subject_id column and the subject table should have a teacher_id column.

What I'm not sure about is how to set up the views (and corresponding controller methods) to allow the addition of a Teacher to a Subject.

Any suggestions (or links to examples) are greatly appreciated. I haven't been able to find anything on this exact case.

---

current set up:

- standard CRUD for a Student object
- standard CRUD for a Project object

I'm likely missing something simple in how to tie these models together (other than the part of changing has_many to habtm) and getting records into the subjects_teachers table, and I still can't find a good example...

Comment: See this also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build the relational table between them. It's impossible to have a many-many relationship without a rel table

First off though, it's a has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects and has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers (commonly referred to as habtm)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

run

```
rails g migration subjects_teachers
```

open up the migration:

```
create_table :subjects_teachers, :id => false do |t| # ID => FALSE = IMPORTANT
  t.references :subject
  t.references :teacher
  # NO TIMESTAMPS
end
```

run
   rake db:migrate and you should be set!

then

see these railscasts for setting up your controllers

http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

Comment: why did someone delete my railscasts links? not appreciated

Comment: I did edit your answer a bit, I unfortunately did not notice the links (weird, I know, I'm confused as to why I did not see it there!). Finally, apologies - will be *much* more careful in future.

Comment: thanks- very helpful with the habtm. I obviously missed this as the solution for a many/many association. The railscasts mentioned were also helpful for setting up the habtm, however they don't really provide any input into controller code. I must not have my models designed properly, as I'm not getting any subjects_teachers records created when adding a subject. I'll edit my question to include more info on my current setup